# Imwrite function in Matlab doesnt save all the images

Tags: image, matlab, url, google-image-search

I have a series of images in url obtained from Google, My question is

1. Why imwrite doesn't not save all the images in the link? More precise, I stored the extracted  image in im =imread(images), but the problem occurs when the number of saved images reaches up to 80 images? Even though the image 81 is existed in the "im" variable but does not pass to the imwrite to save it?
2. Is the problem happening because I have limited access to a number of images from Google? or is it because the imwrite function has a problem?

Is there anyone who can explain to me why such a problem happening?

Comment: can you upload your code?

Comment: preferably code we can copy-paste and execute

Comment: Depending on the size of the images and the way you wrote your script, it is possible that your machine runs out of memory, thus failing to load more images in your matlab workspace. It seems to me that the issue is with your loop, not with imwrite, as it works for your first 80 images.

Comment: @Jigg, thank you for the clarification. very useful points out

Comment: @user2867655 no problem. Again, if you show your code, you will get more help.

Comment: @Jigg, I have updated my question with a code...Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: @user2867655 you edited out a big chunk of your code, I see nothing wrong in what you have left here. You can try to add a line like `size(im)` without semicolon to track if `imread` works all along your loop.

Comment: @user2867655 I wonder if it has something to do with the maximal number of images displayed per page by Google. `readurl` will only read the html in the first search page. It is just a guess.

Comment: @Jigg, probably that can be an issue.

Comment: @user2867655 My proxy settings are blocking the download of the images. I wonder if it is also the case for you. I'm sorry but I have to give up, too much other things to do… Good luck!

Comment: @Jigg  Thanx, I would highly appreciate if you can point out how to save the images instead of urwrite( I mean can u update the code below and let me know to save the image because in your code, you just determine the  file path but didnt mentioned how u save the image afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the imwrite line in your loop with something like (with `k` being your loop increment):

```
filepath{k}=fullfile(imgpath,T_MODE,keyword,strcat('img_',num2str(count_save),'.jpg');
imageSize{k}=size(im);
```

Run the loop once and browse through the resulting cells to see if the name of the file is always different (otherwise it will overwrite the existing files) and that the size of the images are not zero. Then you will have ruled out two reasons for your images not saving.

Comment: thank you so much, it seems working fine. but the images are not saved to the folder why? Now I can say it is working fine but they are not saved to the folder? can u please point out me why or is there anything else I can do. I means all the images size is displayed but nothing in the file

Comment: when i use imwrite (im, filepath{k}); I have the problem mentioned above, but when i am not using the imwrite, I can read the entire images retrieved by Google

Comment: @user2867655 it beats me, I don't know why it would suddenly stop working. If you show all your code again, I can try it on my machine and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: @user2867655 ok, I copied it.

Comment: you might need to add this to the urlreadwrite.m in matlab at line 69  .

urlConnection.setRequestProperty('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 ((Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3)')